# Send int? parameter to command UWP

Tags: binding, uwp, int, icommand

I have a list ListView type. Current selected index of list is binded to int? property. I want to send selected index as parameter to Execute method of ICommand interface like that:

```
CommandParameter="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedIndex}"
```

When i debug execute method, debugger is tell that parameter is null. But selected index is have value. How can i send binded int? parameter to this method? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CommandParameter="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedIndex, Mode=OneWay}"
```

use mode = oneway so that u can get updated value of selected index everytime it changes. Also make sure your ViewModel implements **INotifyPropertyChanged** for this to work properly. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged